# Accidentally formatted High Sierra operating system, how to reinstall?

Tags: high-sierra, disk-format

A family member has accidentally formatted her High Sierra operating system on her Apple computer. Over the phone, she asked me how to download and reinstall the operating system again. I haven't much experience with Apple ecosystem, can anybody suggest a solution? Sorry if this question looks like a stupid one.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Ask Different. Follow the steps described here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904. She will need Internet access and, depending on the speed of the connection, patience, but the method described works, I tried it myself some time ago when replacing the internal hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the build in Restore.

As the computer restarts, hold down the `Command (⌘) – Option (⌥) – R` combination immediately upon hearing the startup chime.

Follow the instructions on the screen.